# How do I convert BERT embeddings into a tensor for feeding into an LSTM?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying to replace Word2Vec word embeddings by sentence embeddings by BERT in a siamese LSTM network (https://github.com/eliorc/Medium/blob/master/MaLSTM.ipynb). However my BERT embeddings are (1,768) shaped matrix and not tensors that can be fed to a keras layer. I wanted to know if it would be possible to convert it.

I have found a way to replace word embeddings by Universal sentence embeddings (http://hunterheidenreich.com/blog/google-universal-sentence-encoder-in-keras/) I tried to modify the code of the LSTM to use BERT sentence embeddings from the following service (https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service#what-is-it).

```
# Model variables for LSTM 
n_hidden = 50
gradient_clipping_norm = 1.25
batch_size = 64
n_epoch = 25

def BERTEmbedding(x): 
   #x is an input tensor
    encoded= bc.encode(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))
    return encoded

def exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(left, right):
    ''' Helper function for the similarity estimate of the LSTMs outputs'''
    return K.exp(-K.sum(K.abs(left-right), axis=1, keepdims=True))

left_input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
right_input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)

encoded_left = Lambda(BERTEmbedding, output_shape=(768, ))(left_input_text)
encoded_right = Lambda(BERTEmbedding, output_shape=(768, ))(right_input_text)

# Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden)

left_output = shared_lstm(encoded_left)
right_output = shared_lstm(encoded_right)
```

I am getting the following error message TypeError: "Tensor("lambda_3/Squeeze:0", dtype=string)" must be , but received class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating BERT sentence embedding into a siamese LSTM network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980868/integrating-bert-sentence-embedding-into-a-siamese-lstm-network)

Answer (score 1):

LSTM takes three dimensional input `[ Batch_size, sequence_length, feature_dim ]`

From bert you can get two types of embeddings :

1. Token representation for each sequence
2. 'CLS' token representation [ where 'CLS' represent 'CLASSIFICATION ]

[image]

[image]

- If you take Token 'CLS' representation, it would be `[1,768]` but if
  you take all sequence output it will be `[ len of sequence, 768 ]`

  Now if you train the model in batch, it will become

  `[ Batch_size,len_of_sentence, 768]` that's what LSTM encoder takes.
- An alternative way, You can add one extra dim `[batch_size, 768, 1]`
  and feed it to LSTM.

  Adding extra dim in sequence length doesn't make sense because LSTM
  unfold according to the len of sequence.